# Why didn't Time Lords return in the end of The Time of The Doctor?

Tags: doctor-who

From [The Time of The Doctor transcript](http://www.chakoteya.net/DoctorWho/33-16.html):

> HANDLES: Message decoding. Message analysis proceeding. Information available. The message is a request for information.
>   DOCTOR: It's a question. Why can't you just say it's a question?
>   HANDLES: It is being projected through all of time and space on a repeating cycle.
>   DOCTOR: The oldest question in the universe, hidden in plain sight.
>   HANDLES: Warning. Translation will be available to all lifeforms in range. Translation follows. Doctor who? (slightly different voice each time.) Doctor who? Doctor who? Doctor who? Doctor who? Doctor who? Doctor who?
>   (The Daleks hear it, and the Cybermen, and -)
>
> [Papal Mainframe]
>
> VOICE [OC]: Doctor who? Doctor who?
>   TASHA: Patch me through to the Doctor. Now!
>
> [Tower]
>
> DOCTOR: A question only I could answer. A truth field to make sure I'm not lying. If I give my name, they'll know they've found the right place and that it's safe to come through.

In the end, Time Lords listened Clara's request and gave regeneration energy to The Doctor from the crack in the reality. It means that they believed that The Doctor was there. Wouldn't it be safe for them to return? Why didn't they return?

Comment: It's possible that they did, just not to that specific location/time/dimension.  Missy seemed to suggest that they had, but if so, it seems they are taking action to stay hidden.  All things considered, not the worst idea -- Much like the Doctor getting 'too big', the Time Lords eventually became embroiled in a huge time war; working behind the scenes and believed to be a myth could be a far better idea.  In the past, they were a bit to arrogant for that, but their recent experience may have helped change that.

Comment: The true fate of Gallifrey remains a mystery yet to be revealed in the series!

Comment: Actually, we know that Capaldi's doctor will make it to the pre-time-locked rendezvous. Those eyes in The Day of The Doctor...

Comment: @Elliott Yeah. It's still in Capaldi's future..

Comment: @SachinShekhar Which could be the past. I'm still waiting for the Doctor to be Merlin (again).

Answer (score 2):

I really think they did return.

Evidence (from Day of the Doctor):

- The title was "Gallifrey Falls no more"
- I never forget a face ... revisit a few favorites

In the "Day of the Doctor" it is implied that Gallifrey was rescued, and is hidden.

Instead of returning obviously in front of the entire universe after (again) defeating the Dalek race, they may have chosen to not rouse the fear/anger/hubris/... of every sentient race in the universe.

Game theory suggests that discreet re-entry might be a better option.

Comment: I think the question is about why they didn't return to out universe, as opposed to staying in the "pocket dimensions" that Gallifrey was put in in "The Day of the Doctor" to save it from destruction. As for the "revisit a few favorites" line, I think the implication was that the Curator was a future incarnation of the Doctor, not some other Time Lord.

Comment: Who says they didn't return.  They just weren't obvious about it.  The "revisit a few" does indeed mean it was the doctor, but that something substantial had changed in the nature of regeneration.  That is a big enough thing that the master was subject to it - it is somewhat unlikely that the doctor can re-arrange his regenerations, or add more to them.

Comment: Well, we know that in "The Time of the Doctor" the Time Lords were able to grant the Doctor more regenerations beyond his limit of 12, it seemed from that episode that they did so through the crack, i.e. Gallifrey is in another universe on one side of the crack and our universe is on the other side.

Comment: It was an exceptional event, the culmination of many episodes and seasons.

Comment: Sure, but my point is that it's possible in that scene the Time Lords gave him unlimited regenerations, or at least more than 12, so even if we assume The Curator is a very far-future regeneration, you don't necessarily need to assume any additional Time Lord help to explain him.

Comment: I can agree that the Time Lords could have done many things for him.  If a regeneration takes any energy, then in math-nerd technicality, an infinite number of regenerations would require more energy than all the energy in the universe.  :)  Occam's razor helps pare some of the "anything" down - in particular toward what they have already done before.  I was more interested in the "unintended consequences" options because I think that is part of where the fun of a story can live.  Irony, mystery, surprise - unintended consequences amplifies them all.  Beauty is mysterious.

Comment: @Hypnosifl The curator was an old version of the doctor, I have not seen the classic series but checking IMDB it was Tom Baker and is [listed as the doctor](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2779318/fullcredits?ref_=tt_cl_sm#cast) (not the curator) but he was the curator in the museum.

Perhaps the revisit a few favorites meant his previous incarnations or people he has previously seen (peter capaldi has also played a roman in the episode "the fires of Pompeii".

But i wish i knew why the time lords did not come back, i was about to ask the same question here but i realized you already did.